# Can i manipulate blend 4 objects timeline from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, expression-blend, photoshop, timeline

Ok, so i created an image in photoshop and imported it to Blend 4. I also made an animation with that object. I wonder if I can play and stop and manipulate that objects timeline in VS2010 via C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you have created a `Storyboard`.

You can start a `Storyboard` using

```
this.Storyboard1.Begin();
```

and stop it with

```
this.Storyboard1.Stop();
```